# @EJB is null in @ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, ejb, websphere-8, managed-bean

I am very new to the web application development. I am trying to implement an EJB call to my ManagedBean method from JSF command button.

here is sample code: 
JSF :

```
<h:commandButton value="CommandButton" action="#{someBean.someBeanMethod}" />
```

ManagedBean :

```
  @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class SomeBeanClient implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @EJB
        private Service service ;

        public String someBeamMethod() throws NamingException  {
             final Future<String> red = service.someAsyncMethod();
             service.someSyncMethod();
            return "DummyValue";
        }
    }
```

EJB Class  :

```
 @Stateless
    public class Service {

        @Asynchronous
        public Future<String> someAsyncMethod(){
             try {
                 System.out.println("Gd nyt");
                 Thread.sleep(10000);
                 System.out.println("Gd mrning");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
             return new AsyncResult<String>("success");
        }
        public void someSyncMethod(){
                 System.out.println("Gd Day");
        }
    }
```

Expecting S.O.P in following order :
Gd nyt
Gd Day
Gd mrning

Actual Result:

```
servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause Faces Servlet: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error calling action method of component with id paneForm:content:PushToGIT:_idJsp72:_idJsp165
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:154)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.security.SecurityCheckPointFilter.doFilter(SecurityCheckPointFilter.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.servlets.filter.IlrAccessFilter.doFilter(IlrAccessFilter.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)

Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Exception while invoking expression #{someBean.someBeanMethod}
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:61)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tiaa.brms.ejb.SomeBeanClient.someBeanMethod(SomeBeanClient.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:132)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: What 'places'  did you find and in what way did they not help. Please improve your answer as things like this are requested as one of the first things in [ask]

Comment: Think of it in a non-JSF related way. What does it take a long time exactly? Uploading the file? Processing it? Depending on this, you might consider a solution or other..

Comment: the JSF command button performs some remote files download ,compare with local files and finally uploading the changes to remote again.Hence it takes some time , forcing the user to seat idle during the entire process.

Comment: Did you check where what the NPE actually is?

Comment: service.someAsyncMethod() part throwing the null pointer exception.
looks like EJB injection is not happening correctly.Not sure if I am missing anything

Comment: Which server are you using? If you had posted the full stack trace, this question wasn't necessary. For now I can only guess that you're actually not using a normal Java EE application server but instead a barebones servletcontainer something like as Tomcat.

Comment: And please notice how BalusC improved your title! Remeber 'good' titles for next questions

Comment: My web application is deployed in WebSphere85

Comment: Check if you dont have any errors during application startup in the SystemOut.log, also check versions on deployment descriptors application.xml and web.xml if you have them (to be 6.0 and 3.0). Is your EJB code located in WAR or separate module? Your managed bean is called SomeBean and in stack trace you have SomeBeanClient, so stacktrace is inconsistent with the code you are showing...

Comment: And make sure you are using JSF provided by server runtime, and not including custom implementation with your app. Also you may for test change the @EJB with standard ctx.lookup to see whether it will work.

Comment: any errors during application startup >> No, even when not trying to have it Asynchronously it is working fine. 
Application.xml & web.xml >> default version is "5.0" & "2.4"
EJB Code Location >> located in same ear , placed under Web-Inf/lib
SomeBeanClient & SomeBean >> it was typo , corrected.

Comment: Also I tried @EJB with standard ctx.lookup , but i need more knowledge on how / where to define the lookup String .It would be great if you can help

Comment: For use `@EJB` annotation, and embedding bean in the `war` file, you need versions 6.0 and 3.0. So fix these descriptors and retry. Also check if you see binding message in the SystemOut log during the application start, like CNTR0167I: The server is binding xyz interface to ejb/xyz?